# SQL Query for the most orders regarding type of orders (buy/return)?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sum

I have the following table for the orders:

> Orders: order_no(key), ISBN, quantity, type

*ISBN*: code of the book, 
*quantity*: how many books the customer ordered, 
*type*: either buy or return

My goal is to find **the** book(**ISBN**) with **the most sellings**. 
That means I have to find the sellings of the books but 
counting also the returns of them.

*For example*:
buy 3 books with ISBN 1010,
buy 5 books with ISBN 2020,
return 3 books with ISBN 2020

best-selling book: ISBN:1010

I tried using this query:

```
"SELECT 
    ISBN, SUM( quantity ) as sum
FROM 
    orders
GROUP BY 
    ISBN
ORDER BY
    sum DESC"
```

but apparently it is false.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT ISBN, SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'return' THEN -1 * quantity ELSE quantity END) as sum
FROM orders
GROUP BY ISBN
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you Bassam Mehanni! That works great. I didn't know the use of "case when". :)

Comment: observing that better...it returns the array with orders with 'sum' on DESC. But not just the "best-sellings" ones...If there are 2 books with the same sum how could I know (instead taking into account only the first row)?

Answer (score 0):

You are summing both buys and returns, you should distinguish them. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    ISBN, SUM( IF(type = 'buy', quantity, -quantity) ) as sum
FROM 
    orders
GROUP BY 
    ISBN
ORDER BY
    sum DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem may be with your alias. this works for me:

```
SELECT ISBN, SUM(Qty)
FROM orders
GROUP BY ISBN
ORDER BY SUM(Qty)
```

You should also include a clause like WHERE type = "buy" if you don't want to count the returns in what you do.